# Include nested models but accessing to Proxy objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

Im working in Ember 3.1 and JSON:API format to get data from backend.

My models are something like follow:

```
// Continent model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  countries: hasMany('countries'),
});

// Country model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  president: belongsTo('president'),
  regions: hasMany('region')
});

// President model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
});

// Region model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
});
```

The way a fetch my models are:

```
fetchInformation: task(function* () {
    yield get(this, 'store')
      .findRecord('continent', continent,
        {
          include: 'countries,'
          + 'countries.president,'
          + 'countries.regions'
        }
      ).then((continent) => {
        get(continent, 'countries.firstObject') // This one gets resolved properly
        get(continent, 'countries.firstObject.president') // Get Proxy object
        get(continent, 'countries.firstObject.regions.firstObject') // Get Proxy object
      })
```

I thought that by using 'include' and the server replying as JSON:API specs, I would have access to all those properties.

To me it seems that those nested relationships needs to get resolved somehow.

What am I missing? Is there any way to work easily with nested models?

Comment: Relationships are promises by default in Ember Data. To be more perceive they are PromiseProxyObjects: promises that proxies method and properties to the object resolved with. You could find more information about that behavior in Ember Guides: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises You could disable it by setting `{ async: false }` but you should know what you are doing as this disables lazy fetching of related data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, adding {async: false} to hasMany and belongsTo seems to do the trick.

```
// Continent model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  countries: hasMany('countries', {async: false}),
});

// Country model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  president: belongsTo('president', {async: false}),
  regions: hasMany('region', {async: false})
});

// President model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
});

// Region model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
});
```

Comment: Using sync relationships is a tough decision. You should be clear what you are doing and well communicate that decision in your team. Please make sure that you have read documentation about `{ async: false }` and understand what it means.

Comment: The `countries` and `president` information will be side-loaded asynchronously by default. Ember data takes care of fetching these models separately and it will be non-blocking. This is why the Proxy objects might not be immediately fulfilled in `this.store.findRecord()...then()`. What are you trying to do to these properties? What's happening in `.then`?